# Scanf for integer not working as expected when I input float or string

Tags: c, scanf

I'm new to C language and I'm writing this code for fun. In here I take username first and then I'm taking a guess number from the user. And I wrote a function to check whether number is int or not (only need integer inputs.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char userName[30];
    int userGuess, check;
    int checkGuess(int, int);

    printf("Enter your name - ");
    scanf("%s",&userName);
    int i = 0;
    while(++i<=10)
    {
        printf("Enter Your Guess: ");
        check = scanf("%d",&userGuess);
        checkGuess(userGuess, check);
    }
    return 0;
}

int checkGuess(int userGuess, int check)
{
    if(check == 1)
    {
        printf("yes int, %d.\n",userGuess);
    } else
    {
        printf("Not int\n");
    }

}
```

However when I put integers it works fine, but when I put a string or a float it just runs the loop till end.

Comment: Because any input that can't be converted by `scanf` remains in the input buffer. Please use `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Comment: Or clear the input buffer.

Comment: Generally `scanf`is not designed for interactive user input. Use `fgets` and followed by `ssccanf`.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%d",&userGuess);` will return `1` for an input of `1.1` (and just ignore the `.1`) but will fail (return `0`) for an input of `.1`.

Comment: is there any way to do this with `scanf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flush `stdin` when `scanf` fails

```
while (i < 10)
{
    printf("Enter Your Guess: ");
    check = scanf("%d", &userGuess);
    if (check != 1)
    {
        // Flush stdin
        while ((check = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && check != EOF);
    }
    else
    {
        // Increment i only when scanf has success
        i++;
    }
}
```

Take a look to [Why to use fgets() over scanf() in C?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-to-use-fgets-over-scanf-in-c/)

Comment: The problem is I need to collect 10 only **integer ** outputs from the user. is there any way to do that?

Comment: is there any way to get only 10 integer inputs, only using scanf and no flushing stdin?

Comment: I can't use flush

Comment: Why not? such requirement is nonsensical

Comment: According to the guy who made this question it can be done without scanf. I can't figure out how. This will be better if i could show you the whole question.

Comment: Yes, thats why I suggest `fgets` instead of `scanf`, there are tons of examples showing how to use `fgets` and `strtol` in conjunction to achieve this.

Comment: Anyway, even using `fgets` you need to check the user input and flush `stdin` when the user type something larger than the size of the buffer. there are fucntions (not standard) like `getline` and `readline` that does this for you.